# Transient Response of AC Coupled Inverting Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc

The circuit below is from [this App Note.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu871/tidu871.pdf?ts=1592334448477&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

The document describes:

> The capacitors C1 and C2 need to fully charge for the circuit to
> function properly. The definition of fully charged can vary depending
> on the accuracy required for the circuit. If we assume a 12 bit system
> the time required to fully charge the input capacitors is given below.
>
> For 12 bit settling
>
> τ1 = R1C1 = (1kΩ)(10μF) = 0.01s
>
> T1 = ln(2^N)τ1 = ln(2^12) (0.01s) = 0.083s

In the second picture, when the switch is open R1 is about 63k. I want to understand better what really happens here when I use this circuit connected to an ADC. In my case I have a 12 bits ADC, so:

> τ1 = R1C1 = (63kΩ)(10μF) = 630ms
>
> T1 = ln(2^N)τ1 = ln(2^12) (620 ms) = 5.24s

5.24s is way too long. Does this mean I wouldn't sample the signal correctly until the capacitor charges in ~5s?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer should be in milliseconds, not seconds. For 10uF/62K I get a basic time constant of 682mS. F = 1/0.682 = 1.466HZ. R would have to be 500K to get the time you calculated. Your initial results were in mS, so did you loose track of the decimal point?

Comment: Your schematic is hard to decipher. What is +3V3? Supply voltage? What an inverted input is connected to? What is the part at the nearest node to the left of pin 3? Between an opamp pin 3 and C16?

Comment: 3.3V is supply voltage and Non Inverting pin is connected to Vcc/2 or 1.65V.

Comment: Your design uses a unity gain inverting configuration. To guarantee stability, you use a capacitor C17 (capacitance not specified in your drawing) in the feedback loop. Why do not use a recommended configuration of ADC driver with OPA376? Section 8.1.3 Driving an Analog-to-Digital Converter, https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa376.pdf? And why your sacrifice precision when lowering supply voltage to 3.3V?

Answer (score 0):

C18 is a blocking capacitor. The gain in this configuration is

`abs(Gain) = 1/(1+1/(ω∙RC)^2)`

Quite contrary to your fears, not fast, but slow changing signals, with the characteristic frequencies less than `6.28/((R14+R15)∙C18) ≈ 10 Hz`, are filtered out.

The configuration you used is an **AC Coupled Inverting Amplifier**. For precise DC measurements, use the recommended ADC driver of [the TI OPAx376 document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa376.pdf), Section 8.1.3 Driving an Analog-to-Digital Converter.